# Don't want to return anything from my scala function , how to do it?

Tags: scala, function, for-loop, asynchronous, future

The scenario is like this I have a function `abc()` with return type of `Future[Unit]` now somehow inside this function I call another function `xyz()` which returns up a `Future[List[String]]` and eventually this function `xyz()` is only and last call inside my function `abc()` but as per the scala concept function returns whatever the last statement returns , so due to this I am getting a return mismatch error . What are the different ways to avoid it , I know about one way but that don't looks feasible to be as it increases 2-3 LOC.

```
abc():Future[Unit]={
   for{
        _ <- xyz()
     }
   yield()

}
```

In this way it was not giving an error at least, please also help me understand how for loops handles this futures correctly

Comment: `xyz().map(_ => ())`  that is all you need, or if you have **cats** in scope you can do `xyz().void`

Comment: or just change the return type to `Future[_]`

Comment: "Don't want to return anything from my scala function , how to do it?" – This is impossible. Scala functions *always* return a value if they return. The only way to not return a value is to not return at all, i.e. run an infinite loop, throw an exception, or crash the process.